# Google Earth API not supported in Chrome ?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Has Google has unofficially decided to depreciate the Earth API without officially telling anyone?

Chrome on Mac rev 39 no longer works
Windows Chrome 64-bit user will have the same issue.

Chrome 64-bit supports only 64-bit NPAPI plugins
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6083313?hl=en

The advice given so far has been to have users revert to an older version of chrome.

For Windows users using Google Chrome 32-bit, the Earth API is only supported up to Chrome rev-35
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/index#installing_the_google_earth_plugin

I submitted a enterprise support ticket and have been told that Chrome support officially ended for Chrome rev 37  for both Windows and Mac

I can understand the Chrome team desire to retire NPAPI, but there has virtually no response or notification and depreciation from the geo end of things.

I've seen lots of notice on the depreciation of the "Flash Maps Api" and "Maps V2"

Answer (score 1):

It took a few weeks, but the answer unfortunately is yes

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ca/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html